# Django migrations.RenameField creating new field instead of renaming existing one

Tags: django, django-migrations

I edited a fresh migration file to instead of adding a new field, just rename a field that already exists on the Django Model

This was the only change on this field

```
    migrations.RenameField(
        model_name='my_field',
        old_name='field_old_name',
        new_name='field_new_name',
    ),
```

But after running `manage.py migrate`, I notice that a new field was added (with a default field value) and the old one still there

And when running `manage.py makemigrations` again, it creates a migration to remove the old field

What I can't do, because I would lose the data

Steps:

- new fields added to model (without removing old one to not break code)
- manage.py makemigrations
- code changed to use new field
- migration file edited to use migrations.RenameField
- manage.py migrate

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** I decided to put this one here, because the problem wasn't that obvious

The issue was that I didn't have write permission on the migration file after generating it

So the editions I did, appeared on the VS Code, but weren't saved on the file
So, the migrations applied when running manage.py migrate didn't had the RenameField command

Running `sudo chmod -R 775 <project_folder>` and `sudo chown <user> -R  <project_folder>` solved